# Vaadin 8 Converter behaves different than Vaadin 7 Converter (doesn't update UI)?

Tags: java, converters, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

TL;DR: Is there in Vaadin 8 something similar to Vaadin 7's converter to update the representation of an input field in the UI? I.e. removing all non-digits from the user-input immediately after the input-field lost focus, or converting a decimal to a currency?

Vaadin Forum Link : http://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/15931682

---

We are currently in the process of migrating our Vaadin 7 project to vaadin 8.

In our Vaadin 7 application we had a few Converters. For example this CurrencyConverter:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import com.vaadin.v7.data.util.converter.StringToBigDecimalConverter;
import com.vaadin.v7.data.util.converter.Converter.ConversionException;

/**
 * A converter that adds/removes the euro sign and
 * formats currencies with two decimal places.
 */
public class EuroConverter extends StringToBigDecimalConverter {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal convertToModel(String value,
                                     Class<? extends BigDecimal> targetType,
                                     Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
            return null;
        }
        value = value.replaceAll("[€\\s]", "").trim();
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
            value = "0";
        }
        return super.convertToModel(value, targetType, locale);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToPresentation(BigDecimal value,
                                    Class<? extends String> targetType, 
                                    Locale locale) throws ConversionException {
        if(value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return "€ " + super.convertToPresentation(value, targetType, locale);
    }

    @Override
    protected NumberFormat getFormat(Locale locale) {
        // Always display currency with two decimals
        NumberFormat format = super.getFormat(locale);
        if(format instanceof DecimalFormat) {
            ((DecimalFormat)format).setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            ((DecimalFormat)format).setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        }
        return format;
    }
}
```

When you load the page with this converter, and the initial value was `null`, it would show nothing in the TextField. If the initial value that was previously saved was `"1234"`, it would show `€ 1.234,00` in the TextField. Which is all good and well.
If you would change this initial value to `"987"`, the binding with converter would save "987" in the object and immediately show `€ 987,00` in the TextField, as soon as you type in the TextField.

In our Vaadin 8 migration we've changed it to this:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import com.vaadin.data.Result;
import com.vaadin.data.ValueContext;
import com.vaadin.data.converter.StringToBigDecimalConverter;

/**
 * A converter that adds/removes the euro sign and formats currencies with two
 * decimal places.
 */
public class EuroConverter extends StringToBigDecimalConverter {

    public EuroConverter() {
        super("defaultErrorMessage");
    }

    public EuroConverter(String errorMessage) {
        super(errorMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public Result<BigDecimal> convertToModel(String value, ValueContext context) {
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(value)){
            return Result.ok(null);
        }
        value = value.replaceAll("[€\\s]", "").trim();
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(value)){
            value = "0";
        }
        return super.convertToModel(value, context);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToPresentation(BigDecimal value, ValueContext context) {
        if(value == null){
            return convertToPresentation(BigDecimal.ZERO, context);
        }
        return "€ " + super.convertToPresentation(value, context);
    }

    @Override
    protected NumberFormat getFormat(Locale locale) {
        // Always display currency with two decimals
        NumberFormat format = super.getFormat(locale);
        if(format instanceof DecimalFormat){
            ((DecimalFormat)format).setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            ((DecimalFormat)format).setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        }
        return format;
    }
}
```

I would expect the same behavior as in Vaadin 7, but instead it behaves like this:

> When you load the page with this converter, and the initial value was `null`, it would show nothing in the TextField. If the initial value that was previously saved was `"1234"`, it would show `€ 1.234,00` in the TextField. Which is all good and well.
>   If you would change this initial value to `"987"`, the binding with converter would save "987" in the object <s>and immediately show `€ 987,00` in the TextField</s>, as soon as you type in the TextField.

It doesn't update the value in the TextField.. It will still display `987`. It almost seems as if Vaadin 8 converters are only used from user-input to domain-model through the binding, but not to change what has been put in.

Another change is that the converter is now put on the Binding itself in Vaadin 8, instead of the TextField in Vaadin 7.

Here is a gif with the behavior of Vaadin 7 / what I'm looking for in the top input field, and the current Vaadin 8 behavior in the bottom input field:

[image]

---

**EDIT: Some things we've tried:**

I create a Test Page with just a single TextField, single binding and single Converter:

```
TextField inputField = new TextField("Test");
Binder<PiggyBank> binder = new Binder<PiggyBank>();

// PiggyBank only has a property `amount` with getter & setter (see below)
PiggyBank piggyBank = new PiggyBank();
piggyBank.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(1234))

binder.forField(inputField)
      .withConverter(new EuroConverter())
      .bind(PiggyBank::getAmount, PiggyBank::setAmount);
//1
binder.setBean(piggyBank);
//2

addComponent(inputField);
```

This will show `€ 1.234,00` initially, and when you type `"987"` it will write `987` to the object (but will still show `987` instead of `€ 987,00`).

Some things to note:

1. If we add `piggyBank.setAmount(456);` at line 1, it will show `€ 456,00` in the UI's TextField initially.
2. If we add `piggyBank.setAmount(456);` at line 2 instead of line 1, it will still show `€ 1.234,00` in the UI's TextField! So the converter's `convertToPresentation` method isn't triggered at all anymore after the `binder.setBean(piggyBank)`.
3. If we add `piggyBank.setAmount(456);` at line 1, and remove `binder.setBean(piggyBank);` it still shows `€ 1.234,00` instead of `€ 456,00`!

We have been able to find an ugly work-around, which is as follows:

```
inputField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.BLUR);
inputField.addBlurListener(new BlurListener() {

    @Override
    public void blur(BlurEvent event) {
        if(binder.isValid()) {
            binder.readBean(binder.getBean());
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, we just read the bean every time the input field value changes. With this change the value is still correctly saved to the model, and is now also triggering the `convertToPresentation` method of the converter after that, correctly displaying `€ 987,00` (although it still incorrectly displays `€ 1.234,00` instead of `€ 456,00` in the cases 2 and 3 of the numbered list above).

We've also tried inline lambda converters instead of an object; trying some things with `binder.forMemberField`; trying some things with `binder.bindInstanceFields`; trying to retrieve the set binders somehow, which isn't possible; etc. etc. We've tried all kind of things, but the Vaadin 8 Converter just doesn't work as it did in Vaadin 7, and we were unable to find an alternative or even proper work-around for this.

---

PiggyBank code on request in the comments:

```
public class PiggyBank {

    private BigDecimal amount;

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount){
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the code for the class `PiggyBank` to the question

Comment: @petey Done. Like I mentioned, it's just a class with `amount` with getter & setter..

Comment: going to edit `piggyBank.setAmount(1234);` to `piggyBank.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(1234));`

Comment: So, I played around with this and I've had to do something very similar.  If this behavior was working in vaadin 7 (I am only on 8), it is likely you found a bug that needs reporting.

Comment: @petey Thanks for the correction-edit. And yes, it was indeed working the way I described it in Vaadin 7. My colleague asked a similar question as me on the Vaadin Forum, but we're both suspecting it's indeed a bug (or they've changed it on purpose and we are unable to figure out nor find any information about an alternative. I'm also surprised I don't see any mention of this in Vaadin 7 to 8 migration posts I've seen.

Comment: Anytime kevin, since I found this question to be of massive interest & although I couldn't find a solution to your question,  here is my workaround where I apply a change listener on the binder instead of the input field: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dd802bd820ae7251cce93450dbe50034 . Can you add a link to the forum post for me to follow?

Comment: @petey https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/15931682

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed in Vaadin 8.12.1. Ref. https://github.com/vaadin/framework/pull/12132